# How to select x or y members of each group based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Using SQL Server 2012. I have thousands of groups in a table and I need to be able to select either **everything but** the top member or **everything but** the top two members of each group based on a quantity each group member has. The groups are not explicitly called out, but I can assign group numbers using a window function. To illustrate my question, here's some sample data:

```
Group   Attribute   ProductClass Product    Quantity
1       abc         xaxa         xx1000     16
1       abc         xaxa         xx1019     15
1       def         xaxa         xx1938     13
1       abc         xaxa         xx1021     10
2       def         xaxa         xx1031     18
2       def         xaxa         xx3013     17
2       abc         xaxa         xx4810     14
3       abc         xaxb         xx0110     18
3       def         xaxb         xx3810     15
3       def         xaxb         xx2010     11
3       def         xaxb         xx1002     8
3       def         xaxb         xx1040     2
3       abc         xaxb         xx0023     2
4       def         xaxb         xx4918     14
4       abc         xaxb         xx1414     11
4       abc         xaxb         xx4182     11
4       def         xaxb         xx1004     2
```

Here's the desired output:

```
Group   Attribute   ProductClass Product    Quantity
1       def         xaxa         xx1938     13
1       abc         xaxa         xx1021     10
2       def         xaxa         xx3013     17
2       abc         xaxa         xx4810     14
3       def         xaxb         xx2010     11
3       def         xaxb         xx1002     8
3       def         xaxb         xx1040     2
3       abc         xaxb         xx0023     2
4       abc         xaxb         xx1414     11
4       abc         xaxb         xx4182     11
4       def         xaxb         xx1004     2
```

There are only two attributes in the "attribute" column. Note that for "abc" I want the top two products by quantity, while for "def" I just want the top product by quantity.

I've created code that can select for **everything but** the top row for each group, and code that can assign a group name. I just can't get beyond this part:

```
SELECT 
      p.Group,
      p.Attribute,
      p.ProductClass,
      p.Product,
      p.Quantity
 FROM (SELECT *,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ProductClass, Product ORDER BY Quantity DESC) AS RowNum,
              DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY ProductClass, Product) AS Group
         FROM table
        WHERE brand = 'brand') AS p
WHERE RowNum > 1;
```

Note that ProductClass and Product together create the unique groupings.

Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: Your code actually gets *all but* the top row in each group, but it is close enough.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, thanks for pointing that out. That's actually the behavior I want. I edited the post to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

`Rank()` instead of `row_number()` almost gets you there.  The problem is that the rows are tied for 2nd place, not 3rd.

```
SELECT p.Group, p.Attribute, p.ProductClass, p.Product, p.Quantity
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ProductClass, Product ORDER BY Quantity DESC) AS RowNum,
             COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ProducctClass, Product, Count) as cnt,
             DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ProductClass, Product) AS Group
      FROM table t
      WHERE brand = 'brand'
     ) AS p
WHERE RowNum = 1 OR (RowNum = 2 AND cnt = 1);
```

This gets the top value for each group.  In addition, it will get the second value if it is not duplicated and if it does not match the top value.  That appears to be the logic you want.

Comment: I replied to your comment above. If I want to reverse the behavior of my original post and select everything but the top result or everything but the top two results, what should the `WHERE` clause look like then? `WHERE RowNum = 2 OR (RowNum > 2 AND cnt = 1)`?

Comment: @mowshowitz . . . I think it would be `(RowNum > 1 OR cnt > 1)`.